# Type Error, not a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I've inherited some Javascript, this JS did once work, but for some reason it no longer works.

I have the following script, bear in mind I've chopped this down and outlined the offending sections only:

```
function top_frame() {
    top_frame = top.frames[0].document;
    top_frame.write('<HTML><BODY topmargin=0 leftmargin=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0><IMG SRC="'+image_url+'/options_top.gif" HEIGHT=25 WIDTH=300></BODY></HTML>')
//  top_frame.write('<HTML><BODY BGCOLOR="#339999"><IMG SRC="images/global/options_top.gif" WIDTH=300 HEIGHT=25 ALT="Product options editor" BORDER="0"></BODY></HTML>')
    top_frame.close();
}
function bottom_frame() {
    bottom_frame = top.frames[2].document;
bottom_frame.write('<HTML><BODY topmargin=0 leftmargin=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0><A HREF="javascript:top.update_options()"><IMG SRC="'+image_url+'/options_end.gif" WIDTH=300 HEIGHT=30 ALT="Update and close" BORDER="0"></A></BODY></HTML>')
    bottom_frame.close();
}

</SCRIPT>
<frameset rows="26,*,31" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0"> 

<frame  src="javascript:top.top_frame()"
            scrolling="NO" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="NO"
            NAME="options_top">

<frame  src="javascript:top.show_start()"
            marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="NO" scrolling="auto"
            NAME="options_main">

<frame  src="javascript:top.bottom_frame()" 
            scrolling="NO" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="NO"
            NAME="options_bottom">

</frameset>
</HTML>
```

I'm invoking the functions `bottom_frame()`, `show_start()` and `top_frame()` in the HTML at the bottom of the page. However, I see the following message in the errors tab:

```
TypeError: top.bottom_frame is not a function
```

I see this on each function call. Can anyone suggest what the issue is here?

Comment: here `function bottom_frame() {
    bottom_frame = top.frames[2].document;` you redefined `bottom_frame` from function to document. So, this code work first time, and then fail

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the same name for variable that you have used for the function name

For example, if you define a `function a` as

```
function a(){a =1};
```

and invoke this `a()`, it will output 1;

but next time it will give an error

> Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function

because when it was executed it redefined `a` to a `non-function` type value i.e. 1.

Comment: I've made these changes but I'm still returning the same error.

Comment: @liam what changes have you made?

Comment: I've amended the variable names, they are now different to the function name

Comment: @liam can you share the updated code so that I can find out why is it failing?

Answer (score 1):

`bottom_frame()` isn't defined on the top object. You defined it globally, so call it with the `top`.  So instead of:

```
top.bottom_frame()
```

just call

```
bottom_frame()
```

Comment: `top` refers to top `window` so in this side all ok

Comment: Thanks, however doing this returns the Error: "bottom_frame() is not defined."